# (Web Api Service) The current identity does not have write access

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-8.1, iis-8, permission-denied

I have Win 8.1 Enterprise and a web service that programmed by Web Api
I deploy it into IIS as website

when call "localhost:9810/api/person" url in browser shows following error

```
The current identity (IIS APPPOOL\PersonService) does not have write access to 
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.
```

[image]

How can i solve this problem ? (step by step guideline needed !)

**UPDATE :**

I installed all IIS, .NET 3.5, .NET 4.5 features BUT when call http ://localhost/

browser shows this error !!! WHY ?!!!

```
The current identity (IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool) does not have write access to 
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.
```

[image]

and when call (as admin)

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Aspnet_regiis.exe
```

CMD says :

```
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.33440
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.33440).
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administr
ators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Win
dows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.e
xe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlin
k/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.33440).
```

Comment: Try this out: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -ga "IIS AppPool\PersonService"

Comment: Yes it works NOW IIS localhost and my webService URL works  , dear @Dunken can you explain more ? why my localhost does not work and how your command solve my problems ?

Comment: This command grants access rights to the account to the necessary files and folders ASP.NET uses. You can get some more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @dunken can you put that as an answer. It helped me.